# How can I include video in an eBay auction listing?

Tags: youtube, video, ebay

Is it possible to embed or link to video in an eBay auction listing?  I'm following instructions found online to try to embed a YouTube video by checking the "use old embed code" box, which everyone seems to think I need to do because iframes aren't allowed, but I'm still getting a warning from eBay that I won't be able to post my listing because it includes "non-clickable links".  Now I'm wondering if eBay changed their link policy to disallow embedded videos sometime after the instructions I'm finding were written, or if I'm just doing it wrong, or what.  What's my best option here, and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up ignoring the warning about not being able to post my listing and clicking the "List it" button anyway, and it seems to have gone through.  So maybe the warning was displayed by mistake, and everything is fine?  If I discover otherwise, I'll follow up here....

Comment: FWIW, the auction completed and the (sizable) payment cleared without incident.

Answer (score 0):

From a policy standpoint, you're likely in the clear.

Navigate to the "Links from an eBay listing" tab in eBay's Links Policy.

http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-links.html